# Getting latest command from function, but function exceeds "max-lisp-eval-depth"

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

This defines the Helm-source for `Emacs commands history`, for the Emacs package `Helm`.

```
(defvar helm-source-emacs-commands-history
    (helm-build-sync-source "Emacs commands history"
    :candidates (lambda ()
                    (let ((cmds))
                    (dolist (elem extended-command-history)
                        (push (intern elem) cmds))
                    cmds))
    :coerce #'intern-soft
    :action #'command-execute)
    "Emacs commands history")
```

From this source you get the latest commands that you called with `M-x`. I would like to have a function, that calls the latest command that I called with `M-x` in Emacs earlier. I read the [documentation about list elements](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html).

```
Function: car cons-cell
This function returns the value referred to by the first slot of the cons cell cons-cell. In other words, it returns the CAR of cons-cell.

As a special case, if cons-cell is nil, this function returns nil. Therefore, any list is a valid argument. An error is signaled if the argument is not a cons cell or nil.

(car '(a b c))
    ⇒ a
(car '())
    ⇒ nil
```

So I assume I need to replace the `push` with `car`, and return the result.

```
(dolist (elem extended-command-history)
(car (intern elem)))
```

But I got the error message

```
Debugger entered -- Lisp error (wrong-type-argument listp Info-next)
(Info-Next)
```

The `Info-Next` was indeed the latest command that I called with `M-x`.  However, I don't understand the error. Another way to get the latest called function.

```
(defun foobar ()
    (interactive)
    (call-interactively (intern (car extended-command-history))))
```

After calling `foobar`, I get the following error:

```
funcall-interactively: Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'
```

Any suggestion to get the latest command?

Comment: As a side-note: What you want to do is very similar to `M-x repeat-complex-command`.

Comment: Interesting, when I call `M-x repeat-complex-command`, I get the following message `Redo: (repeat-complex-command 1)`, when pressing Enter, the message is still displayed.

Comment: Try the history of `M-x repeat-complex-command`.

Comment: After figuring it out, it works only when you use the defaul `M-x`, but I would like to get the latest commands from `Helm-M-x`, because I still prefer `Helm-M-x` above the default `M-x`. And as it seems, the `repeat-complex-commands` doesn't include the latest called commands from `Helm-M-x`. But thanks for the suggestion, it's appreciated.

Comment: The error `funcall-interactively: Lisp nesting exceeds max-lisp-eval-depth` is quite reasonable. I think the last command will be `foobar` since it is interactive. Maybe, you should use `cadr` instead of `car` in `foobar`.

Comment: @Tobias now I understand where that error message comes from. It's calling`foobar` and gets stucked in a never-ending loop. Adding `cadr` to it solved it. I wished you have added it as an answer, instead a reply, so I could validate it and others could see it. Thanks, your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post the same question here and on [emacs.stackexchange](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/14612/105). It's not forbidden, of course, but it just makes for more noise for everyone. (Just one opinion.)